# Regex mask with varying ignored characters

Tags: regex

I have a  series of strings which look something like this:

```
foobar | ABC Some text 123
barfoo | DEF Some te 456
```

And I want to mask it such that I get the results

```
ABC123
DEF456
```

respectively. The text in between will always be a substring `Some text` which could potentially contain numbers (e.g. `S0m3 t3xt` or `S0m3 t3`). It will always be a substring starting from the left, so never `me te`.

So clearly I need to start the Regex with something like

```
(?<=| )[A-Z]{3}
```

which gets me `ABC` and `DEF` but I am at a loss of how to effectively concatenate the numbers at the end of the string.

Is there any way to do this with a single expression?

Comment: Do you just want to concatenate fields 3 and 6? There are other (easier) ways to do that than regex.

Comment: Can your `Some text` string contain numbers? If not, why do not just skip anything, but numbers?

Comment: @acfrancis I would love not to use Regex, but unfortunately my hands are tied in this situation, hence why I haven't tagged the question with any programming languages.

Comment: So you just want to use a regex to replace the input line with the concatenated fields?

Comment: @AlmaDo Because I need the `ABC` after the pipe as well. I will update regarding numbers.

Comment: A *substring* of "Some text" or a *prefix* of "Some text"? Also, is "Some text" known right now or only at runtime?

Comment: @Jon Good point! Prefix - I'll update.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See http://regexr.com?375u8

```
(?<=| )([A-Z]{3}).*(\d{3})
```

This will give you three characters in the range of A-Z and three numbers in two capturing groups, allowing you to use these groups to concatenate both to your desired output: `$1$2`

This will even work if your `Some text` contains three numbers inbetween.

In case you want to replace everything with both of your capturing groups, add `.*` in front of the regex:

```
.*(?<=| )([A-Z]{3}).*?(\d{3})
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response! This is giving the output `foobar | ABC123`

Comment: If i get you right, then add `.*` in front of the whole regex, this will replace everything, including the preceding `foobar | `

Answer (score 1):

Another javascript version

```
[
 'foobar | ABC Some text 123',
 'barfoo | DEF Some te 456'
].map(function(v) { 
  return v.replace(/^.*\| ([A-Z]{3}) .* (\d{3})$/, '$1$2'); 
})
```

Gives

```
["ABC123", "DEF456"]
```